# How to deal with long ui-tests in Playwright?

Tags: testing, playwright

I need to launch long tests, but Playwright stops them after 120...ms

I set maximal limit by `test.setTimeout(2147483647);` but it has no effect.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Set the `timeout` property in your playwright.config.ts if you're using typescript.